# Elasticsearch cluster gives READTIMEOUT error

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have a elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes. here is stats output:

```
{"_nodes": {"total": 3, "successful": 3, "failed": 0}}
```

The index has 3 shards and 2 replicas.

I use elasticsearch-dsl==7.4.0 in python django app.

```
ELASTIC = {
"hosts": ["hostname1:9200","hostname2:9200","hostname3:9200"],
"timeout": 10,
"max_retries": 0,
}
connections.configure(default=ELASTIC)
```

sometimes save to index or search elasticsearch returnes this exception:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hostname2', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))
```

why this happens? a cluster in elasticsearch should be highly avaliable but in my case when one of requests to nodes "times out" an exception occures.

Comment: is it a heavy query? try to enable slow query option on elastic logging and see if slow query is the cause.

Comment: what do your Elasticsearch logs show?